# How to cast in jooq in CommonTableExpression

Tags: java, jooq

I have a problem because I'm trying to execute such a sql query in jooq

```
WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS ( SELECT id, parent_id, title, 0 as employee_level, id::VARCHAR as emp_id
FROM
    categories
WHERE
        id = 2
UNION all
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.parent_id,
    e.title,
    employee_level + 1,
    emp_id::VARCHAR || ' --> ' || e.id::VARCHAR

FROM
    categories e
        INNER JOIN subordinates s ON s.id = e.parent_id
) SELECT * FROM subordinates;
```

There is a problem with  "id::VARCHAR as emp_id"

```
CommonTableExpression<?> cte = name("subordinates").fields(
                "id",
                "name",
                "title",
                "employee_level",
                "id::VARCHAR as emp_id"
        )
```

but in the place of fields "**name("subordinates").fields()"** I can only use String and if I write id::VARCHAR as emp_id, it is read as a column. How to add this to get the casted emp_id

i tried to make cast sth like this Categories.CATEGORIES.ID.cast(String.class).as("emp_id") but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The `fields()` method doesn't correspond to the projection within the CTE, but to the declaration of the field names, which is optional. E.g. you could create a CTE like this:

```sql
WITH subordinates (id, name, title, employee_level, emp_id)
```

By using

```java
name("subordinates")
  .fields("id", "name", "title", "employee_level", "emp_id")
  .as(...)
```

Just omit it, and implement your SQL logic in the `Select` part of the CTE.